# This code always shows "not found" whatever the input is

Tags: c

This is a binary search program. But if I give a sorted array as input, the program always shows NOT FOUND as output.

I am a beginner so I tried to remove the if statement

```
void binary(int [],int,int,int);

void main()
{
  int i,a[100],n,beg,end,val;

  printf("enetr the size :\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);

  printf("enter the elements :\n");

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);

  printf("enter the value to be search");
  scanf("%d",&val);

  beg=0;
  end=n-1;
  binary(a,beg,end,val);
}

void  binary(int a[],int end,int beg,int value)
{
  int i,mid,count=0;

  while(beg<=end)
  {
    mid=((beg+end)/2);

    if(a[mid]==value)
    {
      printf("the value is find at the %d position ",mid);
      count=1;
    }

    if(value<a[mid])
      end=mid-1;
    else
      beg=mid+1;
  }

  if(count==0)
    printf("NOT FOUND");
}
```

shows output as NOT FOUND despite of the input

Comment: please avoid  " `` "  in my code

Comment: Can you paste the complete output?

Comment: What happened when you removed the if statement?

Comment: *"This code always shows “not found” whatever the input is"* -- this title is really bad. It's not helpful to identify the class of problem and not helpful to anybody who might encounter the same problem. I would suggest editing it (and also editing the body of the answer, but that's another story).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing the values wrongly in the function.

In the function definition:

```
void binary(int a[],int end,int beg,int value)
```

You call `binary(a,beg,end,val);`, but `end` is the 2nd one.

When passing the values you are passing the `beg` value in the place of `end`. So the while loop is not executing.

Comment: No issues Man, My pleasure